# Message response options symbols intermittently not loaded on mobile chat

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, reply

When selecting a message on MSE chat to reply about half of the time only the flag icon loads. The other icons don't load. The buttons are there, because replying or starring a message is possible when you guesstimate the right location for the trigger.

[image: screenshot of a selected message; none of the tools (reply, star, link) except for the on the far right flag are visible]

Comment: @Mithical might be related, but the banner appears instantaniously when selectibg a message. The banner will also stay the same for some period of time, and then be normal again. Just to become broken again a while later.

Comment: Agree it's not duplicate... another bug, different enough to justify separate bug report. Pity the chances for a fix are lower than 0.06-0.08%. :(

Comment: I've seen this too, and it has nothing to do with having to scroll first. I've reopened it.

Comment: Chat on mobile is clunky at the best of times, but having to guess where the buttons are makes it even worse.