# Can't edit chat messages in the new - at least for 2016 - moblie interface

Tags: support, chat

I can't edit chat messages as in the instruction menu (using the new interface; looks a little out-of-CSS but that's cool). I think they are not available. I know that [Message response options symbols intermittently not loaded on mobile chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357815/message-response-options-symbols-intermittently-not-loaded-on-mobile-chat) exists but its case is the buttons are loading half the time and only flag button is visible in that half time, where in my question there is no edit button or flag button viewable anytime.

I don't know the
reputation requirements or if there is one.

[image]

Comment: Mobile view is deprecated: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views The solution is to use the desktop view / full site.

Comment: @Mark what view? Only chat or everything? Is this similar to end of support things?

Comment: Everything as far as I know, it will eventually die, like the app. The change the view, click the three dots top right in Chrome (looks like Chrome in your screen shot) and check desktop site.

Comment: *Everything as far as I know, it will eventually die* ... so true ...

Comment: Reminds me of [Message response options symbols intermittently not loaded on mobile chat](/q/357815/289905). Probably also related: [Missing features of mobile chat](/q/126874/289905).

Comment: @rene I mean it is universally true - more like the saying _siyalla anithyai_ meaning "everything is subject to the rule of existence and its death"...

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for the facts; I am going to respond to luklag's request... regarding the second question - I am trying it.

Comment: I'm not sure they'll ditch the mobile chat interface along with the [tag:mobile-web]. 'Desktop' chat is not responsive *at all* and chat doesn't get too much love these days.

Comment: @Glorfindel I heard Philippe talk about chat a while back, so we might be in for a surprise

Comment: @Luuklag that would be nice!

Comment: @MarkKirby While the sites proper are killing off mobile views *eventually* for a *usable* responsive view on mobile, the 'new' mobile chat is the *only* way to realistically access the sites. I wouldn't quote that particular post, chapter and worse in terms of chat. I'd like to bring up chat redux in future, when the time is right, certainly but for now, what we got is what we got, warts and all, and nothing is changing for better or worse

Comment: Please note that you can only edit your own messages for two minutes after you post them; are you sure you're within the editing window?

Comment: @Mithical OK. What did you meant by window? was it the time window - if yes, I can't go to the chat right now with my mobile; Is editing available int the desktop mode?

Comment: I mean, were you trying within those two minutes where you can still edit the message, or had two minutes already passed?

Comment: @Mithical in the two minutes period not passed; repeating,  Is editing available in the desktop mode?

Comment: Uh. This one is the buttons not showing up. The dupe is correct. I get affected by these despite having unlimited time to edit my posts as a mod. Primary issue is the slight jankiness of mobile chat

Comment: @JourneymanGeek No, it should be the 2 minute interval - do you know it?

Comment: Its not the 2 minute interval.... The other buttons like reply and star are missing too. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKq8Y.jpg is what you should see

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Okay, then my original question is solved - but I ain't supposed see the edit buttons in the two minute interval? like was the 2 min interval the reason to my question or was it the [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357815/message-response-options-symbols-intermittently-not-loaded-on-mobile-chat) and the 2 minute interval?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I dont think the reply and star button should be there, as it is their own message.

Comment: @Luuklag yeah but the edit should be, look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370800/cant-edit-chat-messages-in-the-new-at-least-for-2016-moblie-interface?noredirect=1#comment1237657_370800

Comment: .... Oh... I'm probably going to need to test this on a non mod account later

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Are you responding to this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370800/cant-edit-chat-messages-in-the-new-at-least-for-2016-moblie-interface?noredirect=1#comment1237657_370800